# Distance between points

Tags: qgis, distance

I have 200 locations of species presence. Now, I want to calculate the distance of nearest point for all 200 points.

For example, if there is a cluster of points A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H, then what is the distance between A and its nearest point? Similarly for each point, what is the distance between their nearest point? For A, nearest point need not to be B. How can I perform this in QGIS 3.8?

Comment: Have you had a look at the tools `SAGA - point distances` or `distance matrix`?

Comment: Or built-in tool `Distance matrix` : https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoranalysis.html#distance-matrix ?

Comment: Or the Nearest Neighbor plugin.